# Changing color space in opencv without changing color of the image

Tags: opencv, color-space

I am working on a project where I read an image load the data into Mat data type. Then, I do some operations on it.

All my operations are done assuming the color space is RGB (BGR as opencv stores in that way). Everything is working fine. I was doing experiment on converting the output image to YUV format. But when I transform the output image from BGR2YUV using the following command I found that the resulting image color is changed completely.

```
cvtColor(img,out,CV_RGB2YCrCb);
```

For example, my output RGB image is green. When I convert this to YUV format and show the resulting image I found it blue and NOT green.
I want a way to convert so that the output also become green.

How can I change the color space from RGB to YUV without changing the colors in the image?

Comment: Because they are just two different representation/coding system of same color. When I transfer a pixel color value from RGB to YUV, there representation code may be changed but they should appear same to my eye.

Answer (score 3):

The colors of the image have not changed, just the coding.
If you convert the color to YUV, then use `imshow()`, it assumes the color is still RGB so it displays it incorrectly.
If you have a YUV image and you want to display it, you first have to convert it back to RGB.

When you ask "How can I change the color space from RGB to YUV without changing the colors in the image?" you are essentially saying "how can I do color conversion without doing color conversion?" which of course is impossible.

Comment: So, it means, imshow and imwrite both function only recognize RGB format? if I have an MAT with YUV format, I have to convert it to RGB first to show it using imshow or imwrite?

Comment: Yes, a Mat is just an array of numbers. Only the programmer knows whether it is YUV or RGB.

Comment: Then I have another question, sometimes we capture data in YUV format directly from camera(like cameras in tablet), in those cases if I want to show the output image color correctly to the display I have to convert the RGB to YUV, right?

Comment: If you read the image  in YUV, and you want to display it, you will need to convert it to RGB.